# Spring Boot Tilt Build for local kubernetes envirnoment - Tilt throws error

Tags: spring, docker, gradle

I have a Spring boot project with Gradle and want to bring it to my local kubernetes cluster via tilt.

Unfortunately, tilt throws the following error during compilation:

It seems like it can't resolve this environment variable.

```
STEP 1/3 — Building Custom Build: [supplier-service]
Custom Build: Injecting Environment Variables
  EXPECTED_REF=supplier-service:tilt-build-1679856709
  EXPECTED_IMAGE=library/supplier-service
  EXPECTED_TAG=tilt-build-1679856709
Running cmd: gradlew bootBuildImage --imageName $EXPECTED_REF
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :resolveMainClassName UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processAot UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileAotJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processAotResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :aotClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :collectReachabilityMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :bootJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :bootBuildImage FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootBuildImage'.
> Unable to parse image reference "$EXPECTED_REF". Image reference must be in the form '[domainHost:port/][path/]name[:tag][@digest]', with 'path' and 'name' containing only [a-z0-9][.][_][-]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
gradlew bootBuildImage --imageName $EXPECTED_REF exited with exit code 1

Build Failed: Custom build "gradlew bootBuildImage --imageName $EXPECTED_REF" failed: exit status 1
```

my tiltfile

```
# Build
custom_build(
    # Name of the container image
    ref = 'supplier-service',
    # Command to build the container image
    command = 'gradlew bootBuildImage --imageName $EXPECTED_REF',

    # Files to watch that trigger a new build
    deps = ['build.gradle', 'src'],

    live_update = [
        sync('src', '/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes')
    ]
)

# Deploy
k8s_yaml(kustomize('k8s'))

# Manage
k8s_resource('supplier-service', port_forwards=['9001'])
```

my project is like this one https://github.com/ThomasVitale/cloud-native-spring-in-action/blob/d416afd2dae63c35fd098a245a32d1c97813854b/Chapter16/16-end/config-service/Tiltfile

tried everything :(

this is the tilt documentation https://docs.tilt.dev/api.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build fails because you are using Windows instead of Linux or Mac. Use double percent signs ( %VARIABLE_NAME% ) instead of dollar sign ( $VARIABLE_NAME ). Try this:

```
# OS Identification
gradlew = "./gradlew"
expected_ref = "$EXPECTED_REF"
if os.name == "nt":
  gradlew = "gradlew.bat"
  expected_ref = "%EXPECTED_REF%"
  
# Build
custom_build(
    # Name of the container image
    ref = 'supplier-service',
    # Command to build the container image
    command = gradlew + ' bootBuildImage --imageName ' + expected_ref,

    # Files to watch that trigger a new build
    deps = ['build.gradle', 'src'],

    live_update = [
        sync('src', '/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes')
    ]
)

# Deploy
k8s_yaml(kustomize('k8s'))

# Manage
k8s_resource('supplier-service', port_forwards=['9001'])
```